# Looking for a specific Prettier option

Tags: javascript, html, angular, prettier

Looking for a **Prettier** option.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a possibility to format code like this and not wrap the first attribute to a new line:

```
<div class="test-class"
     [test-binding]="true"
     (test-binging)="test()"
     any-attr>
</div>
```

Attributes in one column is a desired behaviour (I suppose it's "singleAttributePerLine" option), but default behaviour wraps first attribute to a new line:

```
<div
  class="test-class"
  [test-binding]="true"
  (test-binging)="test()"
  any-attr>
</div>
```

Haven't found any options responsible for moving the first attribute to a new line in docs:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options

I've tried several options like "printWidth" and "singleAttributePerLine" but they are about other format stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prettier is quite an opinionated formatter (= less options to play with).

Right now it's not possible to do that.